# If NSTextView's physical window gets full, it won't update

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstextview

I have an NSTextView that I'm making function as a console. To log stuff, I use the following method:

```
- (void)log:(NSString *)logString
{
    NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString* dateTime = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [[self consoleText] setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n[%@]: %@", [self consoleText].string, dateTime, logString]];

}
```

This method works great until the log window gets full. As soon as the scrollbar appears, the log function causes the program to hang. Why?

#### Edit:

I added some logging and found out that the exact line that is causing the program to hang is:

```
[[self consoleText] setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n[%@]: %@", [self consoleText].string, dateTime, logString]];
```

The particular problem is arising from the `setString:` method in it of itself. If I separate the `stringWithFormat:` and declare the string to set it to beforehand, it still hangs at:

```
[[self consoleText] setString:outputString];
```

but only when the content is large enough to incur a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The true issue here was that this method was called from a background thread. AppKit is not safe in the background thread, so you should to call all UI updates from the main thread. Placing the `setString:` in a main queue asynchronous dispatch fixed the issue:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [[self consoleText] setString:outputString];
});
```

Very odd that it worked fine until a scrollbar needed to appear...